# configure SELinux for Wordpress on Apache, Almalinux

Tags: apache-httpd, selinux, wordpress

I have an issue with SELinux that when enforcing (enabled) causes Wordpress on Apache to throw errors in the header like:

> *Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/html/mywebsite.com/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 183*

or lower in the body like:

> *An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.*

There are a lot of other articles that have these same errors, and most of them talk about connectivity (name resolution, hosting firewalls etc) but none of those are my issues.

If I disable SELinux either by setting `# setenforce 0` or by disabling it in **/etc/selinux/config** then everything works fine.

Looking at rules which seem should suffice..
`# semanage fcontext -l | grep "www/html"`

```
/var/www/html(/.*)?/sites/default/settings\.php    regular file       system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html(/.*)?/uploads(/.*)?                  all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html(/.*)?/wp-content(/.*)?               all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html(/.*)?/wp_backups(/.*)?               all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
```

The current base path for the website is at:
**/var/www/html/mywebsite.com**

Is there something else that needs to be policed to allow it to not throw these errors?
The goal is to utilize SELinux as intended, not to disable it.

Here are the http boolean values as requested

```
$ getsebool -a | grep httpd
httpd_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_mythtv --> off
httpd_can_connect_zabbix --> off
httpd_can_manage_courier_spool --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off
httpd_can_network_relay --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_dbus_avahi --> off
httpd_dbus_sssd --> off
httpd_dontaudit_search_dirs --> off
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_graceful_shutdown --> off
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off
httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> off
httpd_run_ipa --> off
httpd_run_preupgrade --> off
httpd_run_stickshift --> off
httpd_serve_cobbler_files --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_tmp_exec --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> off
httpd_unified --> off
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_fusefs --> off
httpd_use_gpg --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
httpd_use_opencryptoki --> off
httpd_use_openstack --> off
httpd_use_sasl --> off
httpd_verify_dns --> off
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some info about current boolean values regarding httpd `getsebool -a | grep httpd`. Some of them could block httpd from connecting. (ex. httpd_can_network_connect). You can set those values by using `setsebool [boolean] [0|1]` and if it helps use it with **-P** switch to persist across reboots

Comment: Sure thing.. see post edited as comments can't be that long.

Comment: @DaG you hit the nail on the head...
`# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
$ getsebool -a | grep httpd_can_net
httpd_can_network_connect --> on
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off 
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off 
httpd_can_network_relay --> off`

This worked like a charm and the errors went away.